# %s python, making a guessing game

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code, the guessing part works, but not the part that should print the guesses left
I'm a beginner at programming

```
from random import randint
random_number = randint(1, 10)
guesses_left = 3
while guesses_left > 0:
    print "you have %s guesses left" %s (guesses_left)
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: "))
    guesses_left -= 1
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
    else:
        print"You lose.."
```

the `print "you have %s guesses left" %s (guesses_left)` is my problem

please help

I've looked at other similar problems still leaving me clueless

The error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "python", line 5, in <module>
 NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: why do you think it's a problem? there is an error? if so, what is the error message?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the error

Comment: You may consider the newer style formatting, using `{}`. See for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format . Here, that would result in `print "You have {} guesses left".format(guesses_left)`.

Comment: now it's clear, you have an extra 's'

Comment: In addition, since `guesses_left` is an integer, use the integer formatting: `%d` or `{:d}`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following:

```
print "you have %s guesses left" % guesses_left
```

Comment: @WilliamPaulsson No problem! Please accept this answer (the little checkmark) if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line raising the error to:

`print "you have %s guesses left" % str(guesses_left)`